# How to import Google Sheet ID or link from an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I receive an email weekly with a new link to a new spreadsheet each time it is generated. What I would like to be able to do is have a script automatically pull in the sheet ID to an existing worksheet so that the data can be imported.

Here is an example of an email that I receive:

```
Good afternoon, 

Below is the link to the new Report for this week.    

New Report 08/02/21 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JFazdGz16kIJfjPsez-G6vLGKV9u5Vk3OpZAFelwPeo!!/edit?usp=sharing </LINK>

NOTE: The link to the Report will change every week. If you use a link from a previous email it will take you to that week's Report, not the current one.

Please download the file if you need to filter the report. 

Any schedule changes, terminations, and transfers that come in after the weekly Report has been processed will not be reflected in that week's Report. 

Thank you,
```

**Note:** Where I have inserted the  tag is not visible within the email. The text `New Report` is a hyperlink with a link that is similar to the one posted.

All I am looking to extract is either the link itself or the ID that is within the link. Either will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search the string for the sheet address parameters, and then chop off the ending based on the slash /.

```
function findID(tText) {
  const tangotText = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"
  var theStart = tText.search(tangotText)+tangotText.length;
  var newText = tText.slice(theStart,tText.length);
  return newText.slice(0,newText.search("/"));
}


function testFunction(){
  var result = findID("New Report 08/02/21 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JFazdGz16kIJfjPsez-G6vLGKV9u5Vk3OpZAFelwPeo!!/edit?usp=sharing </LINK>");
  Logger.log(result);
}
```